# I want to get started with Google compute platform - [OR-CAC-33]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to get started with Google compute platform, the system won't let me.

When I try to create a new compute resource, I am told I need to sign up for the free trial.  However when I try to sign-up for the free trial, I get the following error:

"You don't have permission to complete this action [OR-CAC-33]"

There seems no way to bypass the free trial...

Anyone else encountered this?

There seems to way to contact Google regarding this :-(

Comment: OR-CAC-33 is billing issue from what I know. Is you credit card valid? Best to reach out to Google Cloud support team [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/?visit_id=637730967459767344-2414323610&rd=1)

Comment: Did you check removing the mayment method and re-adding it? If not please remove your current payment method, clear cache and again add the payment info.

Comment: There are two types of billing accounts. Make sure you are using the correct one for **Google Cloud Platform**.

Comment: If you are using a Google Workspace account it will be limited by your domain settings.  Try using a personal Gmail account instead.  Even create a new one just for this work.